# .htaccess and godaddy domains folders

Tags: .htaccess, web-hosting, multiple-domains

i got a godaddy deluxe plan that allow me to have different websites and domain on the same hosting.
i got 3 websites : website1.com (the main website) , website2.com and website3.com. With godaddy i got the  main folder public_html (where website1 files are hosted) and where i got the folders websites2.com and websites3.com where i have files of other 2 websites. The problem is that i can visit website2.com or website3.com not only by www.website2.com url but also by www.website1.com/website2.com. Websites 2 and 3 must be accessible only by their own domain (ex. wwww.website2.com) the best way to do this is with htaccess file? if yes how? i mean if i put htaccess file inside website2 folder and deny the access to that folder users cant access files 
regardless of which address they used to visite the websisite am i correct? Thanks in advance